# Division in VB.NET only shows the whole number

Tags: vb.net, calculator, division

I'm making a simple calculator code, and when I do the division I want it to show not just the whole number but the decimal number.
This is my division code:

```
 get1.Text = Int(mygive.Text \ rate.Text)
```

I've also tried:

```
get1.Text = Int(mygive.Text / rate.Text)
```

I want it to show numbers like this: 2060.0891

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert the numbers to `Double` prior to doing the division.  `CDbl` is an appropriate [Type Conversion Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2dy91zy.aspx) for this:

```
Dim answer = CDbl(mygive.Text) / CDbl(rate.Text)
get1.Text = answer.ToString()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `Int` is converting everything to whole numbers.  Try converting to double.

Answer (score 0):

It's showing only the whole part of the number because you're declaring an `Integer`, which is insufficient, as it can *only* store whole numbers.

You need to use the `Double` data type.

Also, you're attempting to apply arithmetic operations on `Strings`, which is invalid.
You need to convert those strings to be of the type `Double` before you can do `/` on them.

Comment: VB will convert string to number and back by yourself. So only if converting not possible will throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

Use converting to Double/Decimal

with VB help function:

```
get1.Text = CDec(mygive.Text / rate.Text).ToString()
```

with .NET function

```
get1.Text = Convert.ToDecimal(mygive.Text / rate.Text).ToString()
```

Comment: Please explain what is the expected output of the operator / when applied to two strings

Comment: @Steve, VB automatically convert string to numbers if code expecting this(using Help Convertion functions (CStr, CInt, CDbl,CDec)

Comment: This is true only if you disable OPTION STRICT ON. And this is really a disaster waiting to happen. http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/08/option-strict-and-option-explicit-in-vbnet-2005.html